# android activity life cycle

Tags: android, lifecycle

A have `ActivityA-->ActivityB-->ActivityC`. If user push HomeButton while he is at `ActivityB`, and then he wants to re-open application i want to restart activity `ActivityA`. Well thats working calling `onStop();` and `finish();` in `ActivityB`.

But when user goes from `ActivityB` to `ActivityC` and then wants to return to `ActivityB`, `ActivityB` has already called `finish();` so user will appear at `ActivityA`.

So how to make `ActivityB` available if returning from `ActivityC` and also finish it if user use HomeButton ?

Comment: When a user presses "HomeButton" it means that they want to return to that Activity later, that is the Android's behavior. You cannot override the "HomeButton" as far as I know.

Comment: Don't try to solve this by mucking around with the lifecycle methods. Android provides a mechanism to do exactly what you want. See my answer.

Comment: dont call `finish()` button when moving from `B to C activity`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515936/android-activity-life-cycle-what-are-all-these-methods-for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

on your root activity (the one used by the launcher to start your application) in the manifest. Then, when the user is using your application, as soon as he presses the HOME key, your task will be stripped back to the root (starting) activity.

Comment: +1, just in time). The best answer for me, but seems the question is a little bit different)

Answer (score 0):

when your going from **Activity B** to **Activity C** don't call **finish()** on **Activity B**.

I think your doing like this

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Activity_B.this,Activity_C.class));
 finish();
```

**Remove finish() when moving from Activity B to Activity C.**

[Go to this stackoverflow question for more details you ll get it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870563/i-want-to-end-the-whole-application-when-user-click-back-button-in-android/12871182#12871182)

Answer (score 0):

Don't call method finish() in ActivityB

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Never call onStop() by yourself. These methods are lifecycle methods and called by the android system.